# In react-native-google-places-autocomplete , there is a method to set the inputs initial value, but it doesn't trigger the search query

Tags: react-native, google-api, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

I am trying to pass a saved search term string to prefill into google places autocomplete's input field. The setAddressText method they offer successfully prefills the input, but it does not trigger the search, so no dropdown options open. Only once you type something does the query run, so its obviously listening for an onChangeText event before it runs the query. I therefore don't see the point in the setAddressText method, if you then have to type again anyway. Surely there must be a way to trigger the search, without having to add / takeaway characters manually with the keyboard from the existing search term.

```
  const { googleApiKey } = config

  const ref = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current?.setAddressText(initialValue)
  }, [])

  return (
    <View sx={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
        ref={ref}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        listViewDisplayed="true"
        fetchDetails={true}
        textInputProps={{
          autoFocus: true,
          ...sx
        }}
        onPress={(data, details = null) => {
          console.log("data", data, "details", details)
        }}
        query={{
          key: googleApiKey,
          language: "en",
          components: "country:gb",
          types: types ? types : null
        }}
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Any wisdom on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Full Disclosure: I maintain this library.

This is not currently supported by the library.
There is a feature request open [here](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete/issues/654).